# I am trying to create a simple number guessing game

Tags: java, loops, validation

I ask the user to input a number until the user finds it.
I'm having trouble validating every input whether the user is typing in a number or anything else like char or string.
So basically I'm trying to prevent any mismatch exception error.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I prevent the program from throwing me error if I put String as input instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing code to take input as an integer, then it should come as an error or not move on if it doesn't have an int as an input.

If you're writing code to take a char or a string as an integer, then you should use Integer.parseInt() to convert your input to an int value.

Answer (score 0):

**Try** to parse the text as a number, and if it fails, **catch** the failure and prompt the user to reenter the number.

Should be enough of a hint to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to parse the String as a double and catch a `NumberFormatException` which will indicate that the input is not a valid number.

```
private static boolean isNumber(String s){
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you want to not allow the String `"NaN"` to be accepted as a number, you can check if the String is equal to `"NaN"` before parsing it.

```
private static boolean isNumber(String s){
    if(s.trim().equals("NaN")){
      return false;
    }
    try{
        Double.parseDouble(s);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```